# setenv with list in csh

Tags: shell, unix, csh, tcsh

The following works in tcsh:

```
set SOMEVAR=(1 2 3 4 5 6 7)
```

I need to propagate SOMEVAR to a subprocess, but

```
truffles:rlaplant[154] setenv SOMEVAR (1 2 3 4 5 6 7)
Badly placed ()'s.
```

(I have to do this in csh because I have to `source` the output of some very complex scripts, and it would be a lot of effort to translate them all to Bash.)

Is there a way to do this?

Comment: It seems that the difference may be `set VAR=(...)` vs. `setenv VAR (...)`.  I believe those are two entirely different statements.  The documentation says that `set VAR=(...)` should work in `csh`.

Comment: I admit, I don't really know csh, but -- doesn't `set SOMEVAR=(1 2 3 4 5 6 7)` create an array? And don't environment variables have to be strings?

Comment: @abiessu  yes, that works just fine but that doesn't solve the problem because I need setenv's behavior of exporting variables to subprocesses.

Comment: @ruakh -- ah, yes, probably.  But if it is, csh is abominable for allowing them to be manipulated in the same way.

Comment: @aestrivex perhaps you can get away with running the other scripts using a `csh ./myotherscripts` command within your bash script?

Comment: No, but I can probably generate a similar workaround.  Thanks.

Comment: @aestrivex: Well, maybe, but I mean, Bash has the same behavior: it lets you export strings using `export`, and it will serialize functions into strings if you use `export -f` (which is a bit of a hack, but it lets you pass functions to subprocesses), but I don't think it offers any way to pass an array. All shells are abominable, even if some are more abominable than others. :-)

Comment: Sure but in that case the user knows exactly what weirdness he is doing because he had to go look up the `export -f` flag.  Furthermore, if you create an array in bash, the syntax is sufficiently different from setting an environment variable that you know you did that.

Why I am mad at csh, is that it doesn't treat arrays or environment variables any differently.  You `set` them both with no difference in syntax.  From a naive perspective, what i tried to do in csh "should" have made sense based on the tools I knew.

Comment: Also, csh is just a terrible terrible language with no redeeming qualities whatsoever.  So there's that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`csh`'s internal shell variables can be either strings or arrays. Environment variables can only be strings.

For example, the csh shell variable `$path` mirrors the environment variable `$PATH`. `$path` is an array of directory names; `$PATH` is a single string, consisting of the same directory names separated by `:` characters.

You're going to have to shove your array values in single strings, using some consistent syntax to indicate that they're meant to be arrays. If the elements can never contain any whitespace, then separating the words by spaces is good enough. Otherwise, you might consider using the same mechanism used by `$PATH` and separate the elements by `:` characters.

If the elements can contain `:` characters, and you can't pick some other character that will never appear, things get more complicated. You'll just have to do a bit of programming.

[Obligatory link](http://www.perl.com/doc/FMTEYEWTK/versus/csh.whynot)

Answer (score 1):

You could use this workaround:

```
set tempvar=(1 2 3 4 5 6 7)
setenv somevar "$tempvar"
```

Although I'm not sure it will remain an array.

Comment: It won't; it will be a string with embedded spaces.

Comment: no, it doesn't.  it ends up as a string.  csh apparently has some magic that allows it to deal with strings as pseudo-arrays that can be separated, but the scripts i source will crash if i use strings.

fwiw, i managed to find a different, hacky solution that doesn't directly bear on the question posed.  i think the right answer to this question is that arrays are not environment variables, and csh handles them badly.